# jQuery Translation library

Tags: jquery, translation

I want to allow users translate my web page. I use [this jQuery file](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-translate/issues/attachmentText?id=75&aid=750013000&name=jquery.translate.js&token=1L0HwLT86kEh5_-04-p8OFDPq2w%3A1323813882340) .I am new for this and it is not clear for me how to translate my web page with this. Please let me know how to use this file with any sample code snip.
I referred [this forum](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-translate/issues/detail?id=75)  but couldn't find a solution.

Comment: That plugin let's you translate your site automatically using Google Translation tools, but it [was deprecated from Google](http://blog.programmableweb.com/2011/05/27/google-translate-api-to-go-kaputt-in-december/), and Google now suggests that you use their [**Translate Widgets**](http://translate.google.com/translate_tools) instead.

Comment: Thanks balexandre. but [here](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-translate/),it says that they use *Bing API* (Would you read the last 2 para of [this](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-translate/).)

Comment: Bing is kinda crappy on this, for example I can't use it to trannslate English to Swedish, Danish or any Scandinavian language as the translation is sooo bad! - You can simple add that Google Dropdown and the user can translate your entire page to any language!

Comment: did you check this http://code.google.com/p/jquery-translate/

Comment: Thanks you very much balexandre for your info. I didn't know about Bing well.I tried Google gadget and it worked well and I ll go with it.

Comment: Honestly, nobody wants these automated translations. Especially if your site is in english almost anyone from more educated countries will understand it.

Comment: Thanks Rafee. I ve already mention about that jquery translate in my second comment and i tried it earlier but didn't work.If you have a working sample code demostrating how to use that file, please let us know.Also,but *balexandre* has a deferent view on this.

Comment: @ThiefMaster, I'm not sure that's valid any longer. The improvements made to Google Translate lately are impressive - I read a lot of French with only a loose grasp of the language, and the results via Translate are often near-perfect.

Comment: Yeah, if it's `* => english` it's fine. But `english => *` is often not-so. At least `english => german`